# Immediately Segue After Scanning an Image with AVCaptureDevice

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession

My view scans a barcode then segues to another view where it loads info from a website about the barcode.  My problem is that after scanning the the screen freezes instead of immediately segueing to the new view where it would show a loading indicator until the data loaded. The segue only happens AFTER all the information has loaded or has failed to load etc.  How can I get this transition to happen?

Comment: mind sharing some code please !!

Comment: I'm guessing, since you didn't post any code, that you should take the website loading code out of viewDidLoad (or viewWillAppear:), and put it in viewDidAppear:

Comment: @rdelmar You were correct, this was the exact problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do this processing on the main thread, I'd bet. Read up on Grand Central Dispatch so you can offload this work onto a background thread, leaving your UI responsive.

(If you post code we can be more specific...)

Comment: I think in a lot of cases this will help,  and actually looking into this has helped a lot in some other aspects of my code.  It seems all I needed to do was move my code into ViewDidAppaer though.  Thanks!